# can i use events as persisnt storage?

Tags: solidity, transactions, events, storage

I'm building an application that is a mix of the blockchain and a centralized app.
I need some way for the systems to communicate with each other, for example.
Let's say you can buy some digital asset in my app. you pay for this digital asset using the blockchain and after the transaction succeded, my system needs to see that you really paid for it and only then give you the asset.
because I can't use custom data in a transaction, what I was thinking to do is to create a transaction id in my DB and send it to a costume function that will log this id and the amount paid, then my system will be able to search(in case the system was down and the subscribe didn't fire) for that event by the id and check if the user really paid for the asset.
is it the right approach for a case like this? can I trust the events for a case like that?

Comment: hi @RichardHorrocks it sure helps but the second answer confuses me. I'm not sure what it means in the term of should I use it as a reliable storage or not

Comment: Good question. What the second answer is talking about is chain reorganisations. Often two blocks will be accepted by the network at the same time, but eventually one of those accepted blocks will be invalidated. (Sometimes you get chain forks of up to 3 or 4 blocks length before they are discarded.) What Rob is saying is that you should always wait a few confirmations before trusting the chain - it could be that certain transactions, and therefore events, will be discarded. I think generally people are told to wait for 6 block confirmations.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks thanks a lot!!. I'm only a few days old solidity developer so there is a lot of new things to learn. is there an easy way to check how many confirmations a transaction has in web3?

Comment: Have a look at the event emitter for `sendTransaction` (specifically `confirmation`). It emits an event up to the 12th confirmation, which should be more than enough. -> https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html?highlight=confirmations#eth-sendtransaction-return

Comment: No problem! :-)